# What is an irrational number relevant to computer science?

Tags: computer-science

For a project we're working on right now, we want to pull a Donald Knuth and have a version number that converged towards some irrational number. However, we don't want to use something boring like pi, e, sqrt(2), etc. Is there an irrational number that is particularly relevant to computer science that we could employ?

Comment: I'd ask that question on http://mathoverflow.net/ I'm sure they can give you pretty awesome numbers.

Comment: Do the world a favor and use sensible version numbers. Donald Knuth may get away with it, because his software is so stable, but others shouldn't even try.

Comment: @starblue: If you don't dream of the impossible, no one else will.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be more about mathematics than programming; this is approaching "boat programming."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

how about  [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)?

Comment: I made myself a beaded bracelet with this number on it. It is the best number ever. Truly!

Comment: The golden ratio is traditionally associated with perfection, so as your version numbers increase your program asymptotically tends towards perfection :)

Comment: And makes for a great logo, too.

Comment: In certain circles, the golden ratio is seen a bit negatively.  It's like mathematical homeopathy.  I wouldn't attach it to a project.  An article: http://www.laputanlogic.com/articles/2005/04/14-1647-4601.html

Answer (score 4):

0.1123581321345589144233377...

http://www.google.com/search?q=112358

Answer (score 1):

pi and e are also transcendental numbers.

Check out some [known transcendental numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Known_transcendental_numbers_and_open_problems).

Answer (score 1):

The amount of money on Bill Gates bank account divided by the number of bugs in M$'s product? Pretty irrational to me ;) Only it's always shifting ... So you may end up with version numbers that are going backwards ... Or would they ... hmmm ...

The number would get smaller if Bill's bank account would shrink (okay, that happens: He's spending billions on charity) or when the number of bugs goes up.

Conclusion: It would be version number that's a) irrational, b) steadily shrinking over a longer period of time and c) funny. Bill's bank account can be found in [Forbes list](http://www.forbes.com/2009/03/11/worlds-richest-people-billionaires-2009-billionaires_land.html). It's updated every year which should be OK unless you plan for more releases. It's not 100% accurate but we're dealing with such big numbers, it shouldn't matter until you need more than 5 digits of precision.

Now the number of bugs might be somewhat hard to get by. Maybe ask the guy who posted "still 65'000 bugs left in Vista"?

[SCNR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/SCNR)

Comment: Dude, it's not 1995 anymore, Bill Gates/Microsoft bashing is soooo nineties and 2010 is just around the corner... You have stay up to date, cool people hate staticly typed languages this week.

Comment: Yeah, it's true ... but still ... couldn't really pass this one up. Makes me wonder if that number would be >> 1, around 1 or << 1 :)

Answer (score 1):

π in Base 3: 10.0102110…

Or iⁱ = 0.207879576… or whatever that is in base 3.